# Concatenate two numpy arrays together index-wise

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two 2D numpy arrays:

```
a = np.array([[0,1,2,3,4],
              [0,1,2,3,4],
              [0,1,2,3,4]
              ...
              ])

b = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0],
              [1,1,1,1,1],
              [2,2,2,2,2],
              ...
              ])
```

How would I be able to get a numpy array where each exact index will concatenate together?

```
OUT:
[[0,0], [1,0], [2,0], [3,0], [4,0] [0,1], [1,1], [2,1], [3,1], [4,1] ...]
```

Comment: The two sample arrays don't have the same shape. How do you expect to pair them index-wise? That is, what do you do with un-aligned indexes?

Comment: Apologies, you are right, I did not write the input correctly

Edit: I have made the two sample arrays of the same shape - the initial question stays the same!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want stack

```
result = np.stack((a,b), axis=2)
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 0],
        [2, 0],
        [3, 0],
        [4, 0]],

       [[0, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [2, 1],
        [3, 1],
        [4, 1]],

       [[0, 2],
        [1, 2],
        [2, 2],
        [3, 2],
        [4, 2]]])
```

Taken from @user15270287, you can reshape the results with `np.reshape(result, (-1, 2))`

Comment: To get a 2d array like you want you can do `np.reshape(result, (-1, 2))` after this

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.dstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html):

```
>>> a = np.array([[0,1,2,3,4],
              [0,1,2,3,4],
              [0,1,2,3,4]
              ])

>>> b = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0],
              [1,1,1,1,1],
              [2,2,2,2,2],
              ])

>>> np.dstack((a, b)).reshape(-1, 2)
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [2, 0],
       [3, 0],
       [4, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 1],
       [3, 1],
       [4, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 2],
       [4, 2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def mapper(x):
    temp = []
    for a,b in zip(x[0],x[1]):
        temp.append([a,b])
    return temp

result = list(map(lambda x:mapper(x),zip(a,b)))
```

Output:

```
[[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0], [4, 0]],
 [[0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 1]],
 [[0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 2], [4, 2]]]
```